# Rails cache fetch with failover

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached

We use this to get a value from an external API:

```
def get_value
  Rails.cache.fetch "some_key", expires_in: 15.second do
    # hit some external API
  end
end
```

But sometimes the external API goes down and when we try to hit it, it raises exceptions.

To fix this we'd like to:

1. try updating it every 15 seconds
2. but if it goes offline, use the old value for up to 5 minutes, retrying every 15 seconds or so
3. if it's stale for more than 5 minutes, only then start raising exceptions

Is there a convenient wrapper/library for this or what would be a good solution?  We could code up something custom, but it seems like a common enough use case there should be something battle tested out there.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Didn't end up finding any good solutions, so ended up using this:

```
# This helper is useful for caching a response from an API, where the API is unreliable
# It will try to refresh the value every :expires_in seconds, but if the block throws an exception it will use the old value for up to :fail_in seconds before actually raising the exception

def cache_with_failover key, options=nil
  key_fail = "#{key}_fail"
  options              ||= {}
  options[:expires_in] ||= 15.seconds
  options[:fail_in]    ||= 5.minutes

  val = Rails.cache.read key
  return val if val

  begin
    val = yield
    Rails.cache.write key,      val, expires_in: options[:expires_in]
    Rails.cache.write key_fail, val, expires_in: options[:fail_in]
    return val
  rescue Exception => e
    val = Rails.cache.read key_fail
    return val if val
    raise e
  end
end



# Demo
fail = 10.seconds.from_now
a = cache_with_failover('test', expires_in: 5.seconds, fail_in: 10.seconds) do
  if Time.now < fail
    Time.now
  else
    p 'failed'
    raise 'a'
  end
end
```

An even better solution would probably exponentially back off retries after the first failure.  As it's currently written, it will pummel the api with retries (in the yield) after the first failure.